# Why does copper(II) sulfate solution turn black on addition of excess sodium borohydride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, nanotechnology

In my laboratory experiment, I was supposed to reduce copper(II) sulfate to copper by means of $\ce{NaBH4}$, an indication of which was supposed to be a colour change from blue (copper(II) sulfate) to brown (denoting a suspension of copper nanoparticles). This much was true for a small dropwise addition of $\ce{NaBH4}$.

However, the solution turned black beyond a threshold point when I added sodium borohydride in excess. Is there a possible explanation for this?

Comment: Maybe it converted to copper(II) oxide.

Comment: Depending on size and concentration of particles, color can be deceiving, compared to the bulk or big particle 
 material. Could it be so intense brown looking like black? It seems to me improbable that by another addition of NaBH4 Cu gets oxidized to CuO. I was thinking about CuH, but it is not black either. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_hydride )

Comment: But if really added in excess and quickly, it could alkalize the solution and if hot enough, CuO could be formed.

Comment: Metallic copper can appear black if made of grains which are smaller than the wavelength of the light. Try to add a little diluted acidic solution. If the precipitate remains, it is metallic copper, If it gets dissolved, it is $\ce{CuO}$.

Comment: Why are you talking about $\ce{CuO}$ in the presence of strong reducing agent? Isn't sulfate reduced to sulfide and precipitate $\ce{CuS}$ ?